# Built-in libraries to persist a BTree, equivalent to Java's `FileChannel` and `ByteBuffer`

Tags: go, serialization, persistence, b-tree

So, I wrote this persistent BTree in Java, following the CLRS algorithms.
I used `FileChannel` and `ByteBuffer` to store the tree in a file, reading and writing the nodes when needed.

I tried looking how I could store such a BTree in Go, and discovered `os.File`, which I think could be used the same way as Java's `FileChannel`.
However, I could not find an equivalent for `ByteBuffer`. I looked at `bytes.Buffer`, and I see how this could work, however it does not have the `ByteBuffer`'s handy `putInt`, `putDouble`, etc...

Would I have to implement myself those function to transform ints and doubles to byte arrays? I also looked at `encoding.binary`, but this looks very cumbersome. I understand that I would have to encode my variables to a byte array every time, then copy that byte array to the buffer.

What structures would be recommended in this case?

Comment: You might find Go easier to learn if you read some Go code that does something similar to what you're attempting, as opposed to looking at Java and trying to replicate its behavior in Go.

Comment: Well that was my question, what would be the way to do so in Go. icza provided a very complete answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using the `encoding/gob` package

Using the [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package you can serialize entire trees into a series of bytes and deserialize them with a single method call.

See this example:

```
type Node struct {
    Data     int
    Children []*Node
}

func (n *Node) String() string {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Node[Data: %d, Children: [", n.Data))
    for i, v := range n.Children {
        if i > 0 {
            buf.WriteString(", ")
        }
        buf.WriteString(v.String())
    }
    buf.WriteString("]")
    return buf.String()
}
```

The `Node.String()` method is not required, I only created it to easily print / verify the tree.

Now using `gob` to serialize and deserialize a tree:

```
root := &Node{
    Data: 1,
    Children: []*Node{
        {Data: 2},
        {Data: 3},
    },
}
fmt.Println(root)

buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(root); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var root2 *Node
if err := gob.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(&root2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(root2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tXL2X5E27d)):

```
Node[Data: 1, Children: [Node[Data: 2, Children: [], Node[Data: 3, Children: []]
Node[Data: 1, Children: [Node[Data: 2, Children: [], Node[Data: 3, Children: []]
```

Here I used an in-memory buffer ([`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)), but if you want to save to / load from a file, you don't even need an in-memory buffer, you can directly pass an [`*os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) value to [`gob.NewEncoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#NewEncoder) and [`gob.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#NewDecoder) (as `*os.File` implements both [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) and [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer)).

### Manual serialization / deserialization

Also note that if you don't want to (or can't) use `encoding/gob` to do the complete serialization in one step, you can also use [`binary.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) and [`binary.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) functions to directly write to / read from your file without using any in-memory buffers.

See this example encoding and decoding an `int32` and a `float64` value:

```
var i int32
var f float64

i, f = 1, 3.14

buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, i); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var i2 int32
var f2 float64
if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &i2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &f2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(i2, f2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YcDHhZQicV)):

```
1 3.14
```

Again, you can pass your file directly to `binary.Read()` and `binary.Write()` instead of `*bytes.Buffer`.

### Non-binary serialization

You could also use other, non-binary serialization formats such as JSON.
 The [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package will also be able to serialize / deserialize your entire tree with a single call. Using JSON would be less performant in terms of storage and speed though, but the serialized format would be more human-friendly (more readable / editable), and compatible with other applications / technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `bytes.Buffer` implements the `io.Writer` interface. As a result, you can use [`fmt.Fprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf):

```
func Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

`format` string parameter can be used to write ints and doubles directly into the buffer. See [here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) for details.